# Do any voting system models try to take "realistic" tactical voting into account?

Tags: political-theory, voting-systems, strategic-voting

In standard voting system models ([see example](https://electionscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/comparing_voting_methods_simplicity_group_satisfaction-1.png)), there are two types of voters: honest voters who always choose their preferred candidate(s) and tactical voters who try to maximize the expected weight of their vote. However, in reality, voters are neither perfectly honest nor perfectly tactical; they may not rank more than one candidate on a ranked ballot due to lack of understanding of the system or lack of interest in researching other candidates.

Are there any voting system models that take this into account?

Comment: All systems that I know treat tactical and honest voters the same, since the system has no way of knowing if a vote was tactical or not.  So I question your first line.  The system doesn't include tactical or honest voters. The usual voting systems treat both kinds of voter alike.

Comment: @jamesk Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but it sounds to me like you’re talking about actual voting systems, while JonathanReez is taking about modeling and predicting the outcome of a voting system, such as when people try to determine who would win in a FPTP system vs a STV or Approval voting system

Comment: @JamesK to clarify - I'm talking about [models like this](https://electionscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/comparing_voting_methods_simplicity_group_satisfaction-1.png) which try to rank voting systems based on how they'd work with strategic vs. honest voting or a mix in between. But in the real world people's motivations are much more complex - i.e. someone might cast only a single vote in ranked voting systems because they don't understand how it works.

Comment: Relevant paper: https://www.rangevoting.org/WarrenSmithPages/homepage/rangevote.pdf

Comment: Pope election maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_conclave#Voting (I think what you asked about is around the same issue they have tried to solve)

Comment: I am not aware of voting systems that were designed to induce tactical voting, even when they in fact, make tactical voting possible.

Comment: @ohwilleke I think my question is badly phrased. I'm only talking about ways to evaluate how certain voting methods would perform in practice, not the design of any given voting method. Reading up the current research in this area I've noticed that it seems to assume voters are either honest or tactical, but ignores other dimensions such as voters misunderstanding how the voting works in the first place.

Comment: Related https://www.jstor.org/stable/4092405 and https://www.jstor.org/stable/193818 and https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0010414001034003003 (5-10% voters vote tactically in first past the post British elections with 3+ candidates).

Comment: Also take a look at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10602-023-09393-1 .  Just got published today. [Here is a free copy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dFN5Zd2z3U8-cC2eoVGV7Mj1CxVn92VQ/view) but I think the [original submitted manuscript](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jIhFQfEoxSdyRz5SqEjZotbVDx4xshwM/view) is better.

Comment: "Are there any voting system models that take this into account?" I guess a mixture of the two type of voting models would have the side effect of being well suited to a mixture of honest and tactical voters.

Comment: "...but ignores other dimensions such as voters misunderstanding how the voting works in the first place." That may be ignored because it's difficult to quantify. There are a million ways how one could misunderstand something and the how would influence what voters do instead (including not voting for example). The remedy would also likely not be using a completely different voting model but rather better voter education about the used voting model.

Comment: "lack of interest in researching other candidates" That reminds me of local city council elections. Typically I arrive at the voting booth and never have heard of half of the candidates before. What shall I do? Read days long before such an election? And even then, candidates could lie. That's maybe the advantage of voting for parties. There one can aggregate knowledge about people a bit better.

Comment: The argument that a given voting system might be great in theory but too complicated for the average voter in practice doesn't come up too often in academic analysis of voting systems, but is frequently made when there are efforts to use such a voting system in practice. Would you be interested in an answer elaborating on this?

Comment: To me "realistic tactical voting" is tactical voting that takes the system into account. That means you've got a circular dependency - the voting depends on the system and the system depends on the voting.

Comment: I find the term "honest" rather judgmental. There's nothing "dishonest" about tactical voting, and anyone thinks there is is wildly naive.

Comment: Contrasting "honest" to "tactical" is particularly stupid terminology.

Comment: @Acccumulation what word would you use to define a situation where you like candidate A more than candidate B, but vote for B anyway because of FPTP?

Answer (score 2):

Kenneth Arrow proved, in his [famous impossibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem), no system can be guaranteed to give a reasonable outcome on several criteria all the time:

> In short, the theorem states that no rank-order electoral system can be designed that always satisfies these three "fairness" criteria:

- If every voter prefers alternative X over alternative Y, then the
  group prefers X over Y.
- If every voter's preference between X and Y    remains unchanged,
  then the group's preference between X and Y will    also remain
  unchanged (even if voters' preferences between other    pairs like X
  and Z, Y and Z, or Z and W change)
- There is no "dictator": no single voter possesses the power to
  always determine the group's preference.

But that doesn't mean that some practical systems are not better than others or mostly work well.

But there are specific undesirable outcomes promoted by first past the post systems. Like tactical voting. In the UK, for example, many Labour (left wing) voters may vote LiberalDemocrat (centrist) to out a Conservative (right wing) candidate which some may think is undesirable as it blurs the indicator of what voters actually want in a government.

Single Transferable Vote systems in multi member constituencies (as used in Ireland and some elections in Northern Ireland) vastly reduce the incentive for voters to misstate their "true" preferences as the selection process for winners does a good job processing the ranked preferences in aggregate (not perfect as Arrow showed, but far better than in an FPTP system).

Practical experience shows that voters do not have big problems understanding such systems and that, in practice, they are better at representing their preferences than FPTP alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a frame challenge so I hope it still answers your question.

If you try to design a voting system or compare different voting systems to each other you generally want a voting system that produces the results that would correspond to 100% honest voters.

An individual voter however wants their own candidate to win. So given a voting system and a voter who wants a particular candidate to win, one can ask how this voter should vote to maximize the chances of their candidate. A voter doing this is a tactical voter. Hence what you want in an ideal voting system is that a tactical voter behaves exactly the same way as an honest voter.

To me the conclusion here is that if you only look at voting systems abstractly it is not meaningful to consider more cases than just pure honest and pure tactical voters.

However this changes if you look at real life voters in a real life voting system. Here you can definitely ask whether actual voters are more honest or more tactical, whether this mixture depends on the candidate they support or even whether there are failing tactical voters who try to vote tactically but end up doing worse than an honest vote. I am not aware of any studies trying to look into these kind of questions, it also seems very difficult to judge these things in a secret election.